# DOMOBJECT.y vs DOMOBJECT.offsetTop - Is it ok to use y?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css, zooming

We lazy load some images via offsetTop.

We have noticed, on iOS / Android, whenever the parent container of these images has **zoom** set via css (eg: **zoom:2;**), for some reason these images are given an offsetTop of 0 when accessed via javascript.

Both android and ios have this behavior.

Using the android debugger we were able to find out that there is another way to find the position of the image.

Property **y** seams to have the correct vertical position of these images.

Is it ok to use y ( **eg : document.getElementById('someimg').y** ) instead of offsetTop strictly for ios and android?

Comment: worth mentioning to those who stumble here via google... we have tested ios 4-7, and android 4-4.4 (all that saucelabs has)... and the y property exists and works as expected. so this solution have been pushed to live and appears to work a-ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be OK. offsetTop is a value relative to the elements offsetParent. My guess is that setting the zoom is establishing the offsetParent for the image.

The y co-ordinate is always relative to the initial containing block origin.

The detailed spec for all these properties is the [CSSOM View Module](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-htmlelement-interface)